# How to change css of one class when hovering over child class of another unrelated class?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am new to css especially combinators and am having some trouble with css of some nested div, ul and li elements

Here is a summary of my code.I am trying to change css of div with class "H" when hovering over li elements with class "G".Since the whole thing is inside a single div with class "A" I assume this can be done with css only but I can't figure out the syntax. I am also open to any javascript solution.

HTML

```
<div class="A">
    <div class="B otherClasses">
        <div class="C otherClasses">
            <div class="D otherClasses">
                ...SOMECODE...
            </div>
            <div class="E otherClasses">
                <ul class="F otherClasses">
                    <li>...SOMECODE...</li>
                    <li>...SOMECODE...</li>
                    <li class="G">...SOMECODE...</li>
                    <li class="G">...SOMECODE...</li>
                    <li class="G">...SOMECODE...</li>
                    <li>...SOMECODE...</li>
                    <li class="G">...SOMECODE...</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="H"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

And a vanilla javascript version of the answer (saves loading in any large javascript libraries for something fairly simple)

```js
var g = document.querySelectorAll('.G');
var h = document.querySelector('.H');

for (var i = 0; i < g.length; i++) {
  g[i].addEventListener('mouseover', function() {
    h.textContent = 'hello!';
  });

  g[i].addEventListener('mouseout', function() {
    h.textContent = 'goodbye!';
  });
}
```

```html
<div class="A">
  <div class="B otherClasses">
    <div class="C otherClasses">
      <div class="D otherClasses">
        ...SOMECODE...
      </div>
      <div class="E otherClasses">
        <ul class="F otherClasses">
          <li>...SOMECODE...</li>
          <li>...SOMECODE...</li>
          <li class="G">...SOMECODE...</li>
          <li class="G">...SOMECODE...</li>
          <li class="G">...SOMECODE...</li>
          <li>...SOMECODE...</li>
          <li class="G">...SOMECODE...</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="H">TEST</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately CSS selectors do not help here. If you can use jQuery, one option is:

```
$('.G').on('mouseenter', function() {
    $(this).closest('.B').next('.H').addClass('...');
});
```

The `...` is a placeholder for a CSS class name that modifies the styles of the element.

If you want to remove the class on `mouseleave` event:

```
$('.G').on('mouseenter mouseleave', function(e) {
    $(this).closest('.B').next('.H').toggleClass('...', e.type === 'mouseenter');
});
```

If there is only one `.H` descendant for each `.A` element, you can also use the `.find` method for selecting the target element:

```
$(this).closest('.A').find('.H');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this with CSS, but with JQuery, you can. Here are two functions, one to change the color when hovering, and one to change the color back once you are no longer hovering over that item.

```js
$('li.G').mouseover(function() {
  $('.H').css('color', 'red');
});

$('li.G').mouseout(function() {
  $('.H').css('color', 'black');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="A">
    <div class="B otherClasses">
        <div class="C otherClasses">
            <div class="D otherClasses">
                ...SOMECODE...
            </div>
            <div class="E otherClasses">
                <ul class="F otherClasses">
                    <li>...SOMECODE...</li>
                    <li>...SOMECODE...</li>
                    <li class="G">...SOMECODE...</li>
                    <li class="G">...SOMECODE...</li>
                    <li class="G">...SOMECODE...</li>
                    <li>...SOMECODE...</li>
                    <li class="G">...SOMECODE...</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="H">TEST</div>
</div>
```